# I am looking for one application which is track project details in salesforce organisation only not from outside site access

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange, history-tracking, timezone

I am looking for one application which is track project details in salesforce organisation only not from outside site access,
i searched some apllication like timesheet,timesheet by upland etc which has access from their site but i want that access only from salesforce organisation

Answer (score 0):

There are several native application on Appexchange. Search in project [management category](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/category/project-management) there.

Couple of good applications I have seen:-

1. [Salesforce Agile Accelerator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ps3jEAA) (Free)
2. [Task Ray](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000055lKwEAI)
3. [Work Relay](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000055lKwEAI)